# depending on nth recurrence of job in control M

Tags: control-m

we have a need in control M as follows.
We have two daily jobs in control M say Job A and Job B.
Job A has a recurrence count of 5 per day and Job B needs to depend on say 3rd occurrence of Job A. How can this be achieved in control M configuration?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use RUNCOUNT variable as below.

Do the below for JOB A

do not add the out condition in out condition tab
In steps tab:

ON(STMT=*, CODE=RUNCOUNT=3)
DO Addcondtion

specify the condition name
ex: A-oK

For JOB B

do the below.

Specify in condition as below.

A-OK

Let me know if u need complete structure